# PhoneGap Camera on Android

Tags: cordova, camera

I tried multiple PhoneGap releases, but always I get this error:
`08-14 19:07:52.149: D/CordovaLog(581): file:///android_asset/www/cordova-1.5.0.js: Line 651 : Error in success callback: Camera3 = TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'loading'`
 after I capture a picture on the simulator. In iOS it works fine.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have an error in your success callback. Post some code.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with next code that works in iOS but doesn't in Android:

```
destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
```

This code works on both:

```
destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
```